# How can I teach grep to treat properties-files like text-files

Tags: grep, binary

Since I upgraded grep from 2.16 to 2.21 it treats .properties-files like binary files. This sucks because I like to use `grep -I ...` to exclude binary files from the search results and `.properties-files` are clearly no binary files.

Is there a way to change that behavior?

Comment: Are these text files that you have created yourself? What is creating them? More explicitly: are you sure they don't have a binary header with some readable text?

Answer (score 1):

```
grep --binary-files=text pattern file
```

another solution :

```
strings -a file | grep pattern
```

Comment: A note that running `strings` on untrusted files can make security vulnerable, see: http://lcamtuf.blogspot.com/2014/10/psa-dont-run-strings-on-untrusted-files.html